# How to update virtual machine disk space in VMware Fusion?

Tags: vmware

I'm using Windows 7 on VMware Fusion.

In the hard disk settings of the virtual machine I've set Disk Size to 65GB, I've selected pre-allocate the space and applied.

However when I run Windows 7 I still the old amount of space (and not the 65G), and on the mac I still can see the same space available. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you change the size when the VM was powered off or just suspended?

Comment: @Mark powered off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend the windows disk size from a running windows.

Here is how you do it: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007266

Now that you have extended the VMware image size, you need to start at #6 in the link.

EDIT:

I don't want to write a new answer, and the comment text-box isn't large enough - so here is a more less re-write of the link:

1) extend the VMware image size.

2) attach the HD image to an existing virtual disk of the same OS as the resized image (Virtual Machine Libary->[select the VM to use]->Settings->Hard Disks->[click +]->[select the new HD in left menu]->File name->Choose existing disk...->[navigate to the resized image, and select the .vmdk]->[choose "Share this virtual disk....."]->Open->Apply) - if you will go the safe way, you'll choose "Make a separate copy af the virtual disk" instead of the "Share this virtual disk...."

3) Start the virtual machine that you just attached the new HD to.

4) Now because you are using Windows 7, you need to go to "Start->Computer Management->Disk Manager" and right-click on the partition you need to extend, and select "Extend Volume".

5) power off (shutdown VM) - and remove the HD attached in #2 - don't delete it...!

6) if you in #2 choose to make a copy of the .vmdk, then you need to replace it manually in the VMware image file (package) - right click on the VMware image (.vmwarevm)->Show Package Contents.

7) Power on the virtual machine from #1, and verify the disk size change.

Comment: Could you please [summarize the contents of the link](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/485/1453 "Are answers that just contain a link acceptable?")? Also, are you able to confirm that the KB-article is relevant to VMware **Fusion**? The article points only to VMware ESX and ESXi products.

Comment: @koiyu It is the same procedure with VMware Fusion

Comment: I can confirm that's the same procedure you need to follow if you're running Fusion.

Comment: After expanding the drive in VMWare Fusion for Mac I just did step 4 and resolved issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent VMWare Fusion (e.g., 6.0.2 or later), at least for a Windows XP VM, this happens automatically. Summarized, the steps are:

-a) shut down the VM

-b) go to Settings / Hard Disk, and increase the disk size to the desired value

-c) wait while VMWare Fusion says something like: "Extending disk..."

-d) start the VM.  It will run a file system check and auto-extend the volume as the system boots up.

-e) you may have to restart the VM one more time.

This is much simpler than the analogous process for, say, an Ubuntu Linux VM, which requires some GPartEd magic.

Answer (score -1):

Note: To edit the hard disk size we must remove existing snapshots, so be careful

First, remove any existing snapshots and edit the Hard disk size and launch the VM

### COMMANDS

Run below commands as ROOT user

```
$ fdisk -l
```

```
$ gparted
```

=> Select the File System 'linux-swap' and click on 'Swapoff'

=> Select the File System 'extended' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the right arrow to full-right, then click 'resize/move'

=> Select the File System 'linux-swap' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the left-and-right symbol to full-right, then click 'resize/move' and click 'OK'

=> Select the File System 'extended' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the left arrow to full-right and select Align to 'Cylinder' from drop-down menu, then click 'resize/move'

=> Select the File System 'ext4' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the right arrow to full-right, then click 'Resize'

=> Then either click on 'check symbol' or go to edit and select 'Apply All Operations' then click 'Apply ' and 'Close' (Ignore warnings)

```
$ reboot
```

```
$ fdisk -l
```

### References

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwpzYlfKnrY

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/extending-partitions-on-linux-vmware-virtual-machines/

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Virtual-Machine-Guest-OS-and-VM/Complete-Guide-How-to-Increase-space-on-Linux-vmware/td-p/388872

Comment: The question seems to be about Windows, not Linux.